# document.getElementById returns non existing object on iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, getelementbyid

I have added the below HTML and JavaScript code in an HTML file and loaded it in a `UIWebView`. On tapping the button "Test", no alert is shown. Actually there is no element in the HTML document with id "mydiv". What is wrong with the code ? or can't I use document.getElementById in `UIWebView` ?

```
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="getElement()"/>

function getElement()
{
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    if(typeof (mydiv) == 'undefined')
    {
        alert(typeof (mydiv));
    }
    mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    mydiv.style.width = 100+"px";
    mydiv.style.height = 200+"px";
    mydiv.id = "mydiv";
    document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the same in `actual web browser`, does it work ? Specially check in Safari.

Comment: I didn't. Will check now...

Comment: checked..same on both Safari and Firefox on Mac..

Comment: @iphonic:Same on on simulator Safari also.

Comment: This mean your javascript code is incorrect, I suggest use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: @iphonic:the answer by shaN worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of checking is undefined

 change your code to

```
 if(!mydiv)
    {
        alert(typeof (mydiv));
    }
```

this will alert if mydiv dosent exist
jsfiddle for you [code](http://jsfiddle.net/on5fzuyf/)

Comment: Checked.but same result. Checked on Mac.

Comment: alert is shown if there is no mydiv, change `if(!mydiv)` to `if(mydiv)` if you want alert to be shown if mydiv exists